# Graceful Degradation with JSON.Parse

Tags: asp.net, javascript, json

If a browser doesn't support JSON.parse, would it make sense to include json.js and call parseJSON in lieu?

So the code would looks something like:

```
var z;

if (JSON.parse)
    z = JSON.parse(yada);
else
    z = JSON.parseJSON(yada);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) and keep using the standard JSON.parse/.stringify. json2.js adds those functions if the browser doesn't have them, with the same names so you can keep your calls simple.

Comment: This seems to be the best solution, as it makes older browsers "forward compatible". Be sure to minify json2.js.